# find upward until it meet the matched class

Tags: jquery, css

instead of closest I use parent() but it still couldn't work. I want to traverse up from `a.coupon-code-link` to `.type-coupon`.

here is the demo

http://jsfiddle.net/Lzchh15y/2/

Comment: You need `parents()`. Not `parent()`. And a newer version of jQuery. 1.6 doesn't have `.on`.

Comment: closest() will also work here along with parents() @Learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were following problems in your fiddle.

**1)** `.on` was added in jQuery 1.7 & you are using `1.6.4` in fiddle. If you want to use `1.6.4` use `.live`.

**2)** You have to use `.parents()` instead of `.parent()`.

**3)** You should use `e.preventDefault();` otherwise it'll first try to go the `href` of link.

```
$(document).on('click', '.coupon_type-coupon-code a.coupon-code-link', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).parents('.type-coupon').css({
        'background': '#000'
   }); 
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/Lzchh15y/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `.parents()` not `.parent()` to traverse up. And you might want to use a newer version of jQuery. 1.6.4 does not support `.on()`. It was added in 1.7 [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). If you don't want or can't use a newer version you can use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

So.. with a newer version jQuery it would be:

```
$(document).on('click', '.coupon_type-coupon-code a.coupon-code-link', function (e) {
    $(this).parents('.type-coupon').css({
        'background': '#000'
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzchh15y/5/)

With the version jQuery you use you can do:

```
$('.coupon_type-coupon-code a.coupon-code-link').live('click', function (e) {
    $(this).parents('.type-coupon').css({
        'background': '#000'
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzchh15y/6/)